# Error in MSBVAR R package: 'REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'integer'' (Gibbs sampler)

Tags: c++, r, modeling, bayesian, economics

I have a following problem while using MSBVAR package for R: when I try to calculate the posterior using gibbs.A0() function, I get an error:

```
> A0.posterior <- gibbs.A0(bsvar1, N1=1000, N2=1000)
Normalization Method:  DistanceMLA ( 0 )
Error in gibbs.A0(bsvar1, N1 = 1000, N2 = 1000) : 
  REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'integer'
```

This bsvar is constructed as follows:

```
bsvar1 <- szbsvar(dane1, p=4, z = NULL, lambda0=1, lambda1=0.5,
             lambda3=0.1, lambda4=1, lambda5=1,
             mu5=1, mu6=1, matB_id, qm=4)
```

and the  only integer elements (labeled as "int") of bsvar are "n0", which stands for "m dimensional list of the number of free parameters for the A0 matrix for equation i." , and my identification matrix, but when I type

```
> is.numeric(matB_id)
```

I get

```
[1] TRUE
```

However, I also type:

```
> is.integer(matB_id)

[1] TRUE
```

The matrix with data which I have used for BSVAR estimation has column names and no row names.

Can anyone advise me how to fix this problem, that is, to make gibbs.A0() function work?

Comment: The problem was with the data - some of the columns were 'integer', not 'numeric'.